# Trying to use Rikulo, but failing on dart:coreimpl import

Tags: dart, rikulo

I'm just getting started with dart, and want to try out rikulo.  But upon importing it, I get an error

```
Failed to load resource
  dart:coreimpl
```

According to this:
http://news.dartlang.org/2012/10/coreimpl-finally-waves-goodbye-and-more.html
coreimpl has gone away in October.

How should I start using this?  Is there a specific version of the dart SDK I should use?  Or is there an updated rikulo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah ha, figured it out.

The version you get with this in your pubspec doesn't work

```
dependencies:
  rikulo:
```

But this one does:

```
dependencies:
  rikulo:
    git: git://github.com/rikulo/rikulo.git
```

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Dart is a moving target. Unfortunately, the update of pub is slow, so please use git if there is an issue.